# Mapping Oracle Blob to java string variable

Tags: java, oracle, orm, nullpointerexception, blob

Is it possible to map oracle blob field to java string variable. I am using jdk1.6+oracle 10g(for testing)+spring+hibernate . When i am trying to retrieve the blob field mapped to string it is giving nullpointer exception or the value is not retrieved. I saw posts suggest using java.sql.Blob for mapping Blob fields. But i want to know if it is possible to map it into string. There was no problem in doing so while i was using mysql.

```html
//Mapping of the BLOB field in Data.java entity

@Column(name = "DATA_BLOB")
 @Lob
 private String DataBlob;


/**
  * @return the DataBlob
  */
 
public String getDataBlob() {
  return DataBlob;
 }




//MY METHOD IN DAO INTERFACE FOR RETRIEVING BLOB DATA

public String getData(Long DataId) throws DataAccessException;


//DAO Implementation of the above method

@Override
@Transactional
    public String getData(Long DataId){

    Data data = this.entityManager.find(Data.class, DataId);
    return data.getDataBlob();

 }

//how i call this in my service

String Data = DataDao.getData(DataId);
```

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are having text in a BLOB rather than a CLOB?

Comment: BLOB in Oracle database is a Binary Large Object and can contain up to 4 GB of binary data. CLOB is a Character Large Object and can contain up to 4 GB of character data. When you use BLOB, the binary content can be any bytes (images, video) and not immediately useful for character data, as there might be byte values in the BLOB that cannot be represented as character data. CLOB is designed for character data. LONGBOB I do not know? There is datatype LONG but it is deprecated and not a good idea to use.

Comment: If you are stuck with using BLOB as the datatype of the column in the database even though you are storing characters in it, I think a possible solution can be to use java.sql.Blob and use the getBinaryStream method and then find or code something that can transform a binary stream to a String. I don't know sufficient Java to give a real answer for that - I personally would prefer to switch datatype to CLOB ;-)

Comment: We are storing json file in the blob field. I came across the suggestion of using java.sql.Blob in other posts. But i want to make sure we cant use String for this. Anyway we have to give this data as string to the front end

Comment: Json data works nicely in a CLOB. Then you would have easy conversion to String. If you persist in BLOB, as I said I think you need to use java.sql.Blob as an intermediate to convert the binary stream into a String.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing - once you upgrade to Oracle version 12.1.0.2.0 or later, the database supports querying JSON data in SQL statements - if the JSON is stored in CLOBs :-D